# Facebook connect in iframe- popups shows inside the iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbjs

I'm implementing Facebook connect for a website. The Facebook Connect code is inside an `iframe`. Everything works well but when Facebook is supposed to show a popup dialog (for example `FB.Connect.showFeedDialog` or `FB.Connect.streamPublish`) The popup shows inside the `iframe`.
Since its a small `iframe` window the popup is half hidden.

Any idea on how to solve it is very much appreciated.
Note: the FB login and logout popups do show well.

Answer (score 0):

My window was too small to show the FB iframe properly, so I overrode the private _openFeedDialogIframe function to call the _openFeedDialogWindow:

```
var init = function()
{
    FB.Connect.get_status().waitUntilReady(function(status)
    {
        FB.Connect._openFeedDialogIframe = function(b, a, f)
        {
            FB.Connect._openFeedDialogWindow(b, a, f);
        };
    });
};
FB.ensureInit(init);
```

This forces a popup every time an iframe is to be shown.